# Efficient programming techniques

Tags: java, standards

I am writing a method, and would like to know if the attached code is efficient depending on how it is written:

```
    public boolean isThreeOfKind(PlayingCard[] hand)
    {
//            if(hand[0].getRank() == hand[2].getRank())
//                return true;
//            else if(hand[1].getRank() == hand[3].getRank())
//                return true;
//            else if(hand[2].getRank() == hand[4].getRank())
//                return true;

        return (hand[0].getRank() == hand[2].getRank() || 
                hand[1].getRank() == hand[3].getRank() || 
                hand[2].getRank() == hand[4].getRank());
    }
```

So as you can see I have an if else if statement commented out, and a return statement doing the same thing basically, which would be more efficient and according to coding standards?

Comment: In a land and language far, far away, logical operations were much faster than branching. But modern compilers have turned us all into code monkeys, so just use whatever floats your boat.

Comment: Hmmm looks like the `PlayingCard`s in `hand` better be be sorted by value.  Took me a minute to figure out how this would be 'three of a kind.'  Just sayin'

Comment: Yes it is sorted, the first thin my program does is sort the hand, then evaluate

Answer (score 9):

No difference in efficiency, but definite difference in style, the second one being much better. However, this particular logic is really just

```
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) 
  if (hand[i].getRank() == hand[i+2].getRank()) return true;
return false;
```

Comment: This implementation would also scale past [0...4]. +1

Comment: I especially prefer it because it's so much more clear what the code is doing -- comparing i-th member of an ascending series with the (i+2)nd member to confirm three-of-a-kind. Ascending series is implied (the cards are sorted), otherwise this wouldn't work -- which is another obvious thing now (any error would be much easier to recognize).

Answer (score 3):

This type of question might be better on [CodeReview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com) because it's more of an opinion. But In my opinion it's much easier to read the non-commented portion and performance shouldn't be worried about until it becomes an issue (especially in something like this). For more on that see the Program optimization article on Wikipedia particularly the [When to Optimize](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Premature_optimization#When_to_optimize) section.

Answer (score 0):

As Jeffery said, I'd say readability is more valuable than efficiency in this case (I wouldn't say that's a universal rule).

You might be interested in a concept called [Short-Circuit Evaluation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation). Notice that **|| is a short-circuit operator in Java**. As such, you'll get the same effect as the if statements if the first statement is true (the other two will not be evaluated).

That being said, I'm not sure if those two bits of code compile down into the same function (they might depending on the compiler implementation). **If they do not compile down the same, the second will likely be faster.**

Comment: How do you figure? I can't imagine what would be different, except that the commented-out solution might be faster if the return is implemented repeatedly at all those exit points, where the uncommented version might jump to the common exit point at the end, where the result `true` is then jointly created.

Comment: That's the point of short circuit evaluation. Java won't evaluate the second two elements in the second implementation if the first is true, just like with the if statements.

Edit: The reason I said it might be slower is because I'm not sure what machine code "if" statements compile down into. My guess is that the two statements would compile identically, but I'm not positive.

Answer (score 0):

Or if you prefer only one exit point in the method and array boundary checking:

```
boolean found = false;
for (int i = 0; !found && i < hand.length - 2; i++) 
    found = (hand[i].getRank() == hand[i + 2].getRank());
return found;
```